# sf multipolygon to elevation raster

Tags: r, sf, rasterization

I am trying to create some shadowmaps of the NYC skyline using the shapefiles found here:

[shapefiles of NYC buildings](http://maps.nyc.gov/download/3dmodel/DA_WISE_Multipatch.zip).

I can import them after unbundling the gdb folders. What I have trouble with is converting them into a raster so I can render them using the r rayshader package.  I did successfully create a function to hand roll a shape file that `fasterize` can handle but it's convoluted and the results are unsatisfactory.  Building footprints are not sharp and the building heights are erratic and often wrong.  I suspect there is a better way.

Do you know of one?

Here is the function I came up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(fasterize)

sf_poly_to_raster <- function(sf_obj,res = 10){
  # expects polygon or multipolygon geometry

  # reduce each builting to a single polygon
  sf_obj <- sf_obj %>%
    st_union(by_feature = TRUE)

  # split polygons into xyz points
  sf_obj_pts <- sf_obj %>%
    st_cast("POINT",warn = F)

  # extract the coordinates. We want Z
  sf_obj_coord <-
    sf_obj_pts %>%
    st_coordinates %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(X,Y)

  # take max building height as whole building height.
  sf_obj_z <- sf_obj_pts %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    transmute(BIN,z = sf_obj_coord$Z) %>%
    dplyr::select(BIN,z) %>%
    group_by(BIN) %>%
    summarise(z = max(z))

  # add Z feature back to spatial object
  sf_obj <- left_join(sf_obj,sf_obj_z,by="BIN")

  # Generate empty raster layer and rasterize points
  raster_template <- raster(crs = crs(lower_man),
                            ext = extent(lower_man),
                            res = res)

  sf_obj_raster <- fasterize(sf_obj,
                             raster_template,fun="max",
                             field="z",
                             background = 0)
  return(sf_obj_raster)

}


lower_man <- sf::st_read("data/DA12_3D_Buildings_Multipatch.gdb.zip")
lower_man_ras <-  lower_man %>%
  # some structures resist conversion from multipoly to poly
  # and this breaks the raster conversion. I don't know why but
  # this gets rid of them
  filter(DOITT_ID != 0) %>%
  sf_poly_to_raster()
```

It works partially.

For reproducibility here is the plotting routine I used:

```
library(rayshader)

elev_img <-  lower_man_ras %>% 
  raster::crop(extent(lower_man_ras) *.2)

elev_matrix <- matrix(
  raster::extract(elev_img, raster::extent(elev_img), buffer = 1000),
  nrow = ncol(elev_img),
  ncol = nrow(elev_img)
)

#Plot in 3D
rgl::clear3d()
elev_matrix %>%
  sphere_shade(texture = "bw") %>%
  plot_3d(elev_matrix,zscale=10,zoom = .5)
```

The image below compares the `plot_3d` output with google maps.

[image: shadowmap next to google sat imagerystrong text]

Comment: Seems to be two problems here: one, the height of the buildings seeming "wrong" and two, the "unsharp" footprints. Is the source data wrong on heights? Is the unsharpness due to you rasterizing at too low a resolution or is it the visualisation code struggling with infinite gradients? What does a perfect cube look like?